heroku deployment uncaught runtime error Network Error AxiosError:
I have an app created using create-react-app that displays the position of the ISS on google react maps. I get the position by making a request to nofity api and the map by making a request to google maps. It builds ok in heroku but when i navigate to the URL to view my app...
Mixed Content: The page at '' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint ''. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
i tried changing the requests from http to https but the ISS api does not response.... and there is no documentation on the api site about http/s requests etc
https://github.com/burtscriptor/International-Space-Station-Locator
